# MoveNext for List

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create an application where you press the next button and it shows the next object in a list. In this case an object of Employee, I'm using Linq To SQL. I've read about `MoveNext`, but I don't know how it works and I tried something else which doesn't work (code below). Basically I want to have a next/previous button to get employees from the db.

Here's the code to get all Employees:

```
public List<Employee> GetEmployees()
        {
            var q =
                from a in db.GetTable<Employee>()
                select a;

            List<Employee> employeeList = q.ToList();
            return employeeList;
        }
```

Button click:

```
 private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Increment();
            LoadEmployee();
        }
```

Increment (method) (this is my solution for getting the next object, but it isn't optimal at all):

```
public void Increment()
        {
            if (con.GetEmployee(id) != null)
            {
                id++;
            }
            else
            {
                id += 2;
            }
        }
```

LoadEmployee (method):

```
 public void LoadEmployee()
        {
            Employee e = con.GetEmployees().FirstOrDefault(f => f.id.Equals(id));
            tbId.Text = e.id.ToString();
            tbFname.Text = e.Fname;
            tbLname.Text = e.Lname;
            tbDate.Text = e.Date;

        }
```

Comment: In `GetEmployees()`, isn't `var q = from a in db.GetTable<Employee>() select a; List<Employee> employeeList = q.ToList(); return employeeList;` equivalent to `return db.GetTable<Employee>().ToList();`?

Comment: Maybe, but that isn't really the answer to the question or is it?

Comment: If it was, I would have written an answer.

Comment: since you are using a global anyway you want to make your global an iterator instead of an int and just call next on that.

Comment: Can we see your `GetEmployee(id)` method? Is it any different from just `GetEmployees().FirstOrDefault(f => f.id.Equals(id))`?

Comment: So doesn't `con.GetEmployee(id)` return the employee? Increment the id *before* calling that method, then use the returned employee for displaying...

Comment: But if there's space in between the employees let's say employee with id 1000 and employee with the id 2500, then the application will crash. That is the problem. Yeah the GetEmployee(id) is like that Jashaszun.

Comment: Just remember that  Employee e = con.GetEmployees().FirstOrDefault(f => f.id.Equals(id)); might be null and can also break the application when trying to get its values on e.Fname.

Answer (score 1):

Sir, try this

```
  public void LoadEmployee()
    {
        Employee e = con.GetEmployees();
        tbId.Text = e[id].id.ToString();
        tbFname.Text = e[id].Fname;
        tbLname.Text = e[id].Lname;
        tbDate.Text = e[id].Date;

    }
```

use id as an index of your collection

Answer (score 0):

So to summarise:

- You're using SQL
- And want to take a record with 'next' / 'prev'.

If you look at SQL itself without using cursors, I'd say that translates as a 'skip' and 'take 1'. Linq has these features:

```
// initialize index
int x = -1;

// move next:
var currentEmployee = context.Employees.Skip(++x).FirstOrDefault();
if (currentEmployee == null) 
{
   // End.    
}

// move prev:
if (--x < 0)
{ 
    // move back past start
    x = 0;
}
var currentEmployee = context.Employees.Skip(x).FirstOrDefault();
if (currentEmployee == null) 
{
   // No elements
}
```